# Como enviar variável com link no PHP

Tags: php

então, estou com dúvidas em como fazer esse link no php:

```
<a href="DepoimentosPT-BR.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['idusuario']; ?>">Depoimentos</a></li>
```

como vocês podem ver esse link está no html e depois é chamado o php para enviar a $ com e o ?id.

Quero saber como faço dessa maneira no php mesmo tipo:

```
echo "...";
```

Answer (score 5):

Considerando `$id = $_SESSION['idusuario']`.

1. Concatenando *strings*:

   ```
   echo '<a href="DepoimentosPT-BR.php?id='.$id.'">Depoimentos</a>';
   ```
2. Interpolando *strings*:

   ```
   echo "<a href='DepoimentosPT-BR.php?id={$id}'>Depoimentos</a>";
   ```
3. Formatando *strings* com `sprintf`:

   ```
   echo sprintf("<a href='DepoimentosPT-BR.php?id=%d'>Depoimentos</a>", $id);
   ```
4. Tradução de caracteres da *string*:

   ```
   echo strtr("<a href='DepoimentosPT-BR.php?id={id}'>Depoimentos</a>", '{id}', $id);
   ```

Comment: Valeu meu brother, me ajudou ;;)

Comment: +1 pelo `sprintf`

Comment: @PedroLukas você deve marcar a resposta como a correta para a sua dúvida.